# powershell cmdlet for sending to serial port

Tags: powershell, serial-port, powershell-cmdlet

i'm trying to create a powershell cmdlet which would send a hex string to a COM port using as input argument a string.
i have a small uC on COM, which controls 2 relays based on an input hex string.
i'm completely new to powershell, so ...

### from a cmdline powershell, inputing the commands manually, it works however.
this is what i came up with:

```
using System.Management.Automation;  // Windows PowerShell assembly.
using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort;

namespace ControlPort
{
  // Declare the class as a cmdlet and specify the
  // appropriate verb and noun for the cmdlet name.
  [Cmdlet(VerbsCommunications.Send, "ControlCOM11", SupportsTransactions=true)]
  
  public class SendControlCommand : Cmdlet
  {
    $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM11,9600,None,8,one;
    $port.open();
    
    // Declare the parameters for the cmdlet.
    [Parameter(Mandatory=true)]
    public string command
    {
      get { return command; }
      set { command = value; }
    }
    private string command;

    // Override the ProcessRecord method to process
    // the supplied user name and write out a
    // greeting to the user by calling the WriteObject
    // method.    
    
    protected override void ProcessRecord(command)
    {
        if (TransactionAvailable())
        {
            using (CurrentPSTransaction)
            {
                if(command == "RELAY2ON")
                  {
                    const [Byte[]] $relay2on = 0x52, 0x45, 0x4C, 0x41, 0x59, 0x32, 0x4F, 0x4E, 0x3B;
                    $port.Write($relay2on, 0, $relay2on.Count);
                  }
      
                if(command == "RELAY2OFF")
                  {
                    const [Byte[]] $relay2off = 0x52, 0x45, 0x4C, 0x41, 0x59, 0x32, 0x4F, 0x46, 0x46, 0x3B;
                    $port.Write($relay2off, 0, $relay2off.Count);
                  }
            
            }   
        
        }       
      
    }
  }
}
```

---

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can easily convert this c# code into a compiled PowerShell cmdlet.  Follow the steps here:  https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-c-to-create-powershell-cmdlets-the-basics/#third

Some of your statements will need to be converted into c# syntax first though, namely your variable declarations.  It should be minor adjustments to each line.

Comment: thanks for the great help!